# How can I make the man command not use a pager?

Tags: manpages, pager

How can I force the `man` command to not use a pager, and instead output the whole manpage at once and keep all highlighting?

If I use `man -P cat` or `man | cat`, I lose highlighting.

Comment: You _need_ a better title.

Comment: @Slaks: You mean the answer isn't "Buy him a blackberry"?

Comment: @Matt: Exactly.

Comment: Ops! Did not read it in this way :)))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Long reading of manuals for man, less, groff and grotty finally gave me answer

Highlighting by default is made using backspace sequences: `c\bc` => bold c, `_\bc` => underlined c. But if output as is using cat as pager just outputs plain c in both cases. Also blank lines are squeezed, so to do all this, pager must be set to `ul | cat -s`.

Pager can be set in many ways:

1. using MANPAGER or PAGER variables (MANPAGER is better as PAGER affects not only man command)

   ```
   export MANPAGER='ul | cat -s'
   ```
2. in man.conf

   ```
   PAGER       ul | cat -s
   ```
3. using -P parameter

   ```
   cat -P 'ul | cat -s' …
   ```

   or

   ```
   alias man='man -P "ul | cat -s"'
   ```

Comment: +1, but I only need to use 'ul' as my pager to dump the output to the console with highlighting. I.e. `man -P ul <command>`. Ubuntu 12.04.2.

Answer (score 3):

> man man

```
...
    PAGER          A program to use for interactively delivering
                        man's  output  to  the  screen.   If not set,
                        `more -s' is used.  See more(1).
```

Which means the pager is regulated by PAGER env. variable,
Thus just define PAGER as

```
setenv PAGER cat
```

and enjoy.

Comment: Why the downvote? This may not be the optimal solution, but it's not incorrect. Try it: `$ PAGER=cat man foobar`.

Comment: Isn't using `cat` as a pager essentially the same thing as not using a pager at all?

Comment: The question is about **not** using a pager and this without loosing highlighting.

Comment: When I try this approach, I lose highlighting (on Mac OS X and Ubuntu).

Comment: i also lose highlighting. as a comment in another answer points out, `man -P ul` or `PAGER=ul man` works. TIL about ul…

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, there's always the `-P` switch:

```
man -P cat foo
```

Comment: I already sad that with `-P cat` I use highlighting

Comment: I checked my theory with <code>man -P cat man |tee foo.txt ; less -R foo.txt</code>. The formatting is still there; it just doesn't show up in the command window.

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly what you want (you won't get the output in the console) but you could generate a dvi file with the content of a manual as explained in man's man:

> ```
> man -l -Tdvi ./foo.1x.gz > ./foo.1x.dvi
> ```
>
> This command will decompress and format  the  nroff  source  manual
>     page  ./foo.1x.gz  into a device independent (dvi) file.  The redi‐
>     rection is necessary as the -T flag causes output to be directed to
>     stdout  with  no  pager.  The output could be viewed with a program
>     such as xdvi or further processed into PostScript using  a  program
>     such as dvips.

I've just tested this and opened the dvi file with evince: the highlighting is not lost.

Comment: man on mac has no -l and -T params